# Scrapy - Create a .exe

Tags: windows, scrapy, exe

I am currently developing a web crawler which retrieves data from a specific website and parse it to a xlsx file. I'd like to know if it is possible to create a .exe file where, on windows, you'd only have to execute it to create the webspider, retrieve the data...etc

Thanks

(I'm developing on linux but people using it will be using it on Windows, that's why I'm looking for an easy way for them to use this program)

Comment: Maybe you want pytoexe ... or maybe you want a cmd file rather than an exe file.

Comment: I'll look into the cmd solution, thanks for the idea

Comment: Microsoft would recommend Powershell instead of cmd .... I wouldn't :)